# merging table using date field if common and add new row if date field is not common

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, merge

I am developing house app.I retrieve data using query for expense and income from different table name as expenses and incomes respectively.
If I use expense only then it would print and if i try to mix income value too it give me problem.

Code:

```
 $expenses = $expense->dailyExpense();
 $income = $income->dailyIncome();
 return response()->json(['data' => ['expenses' => $expenses , 'income' => $income] , 'msg' => 'Daily Expense']);
```

the query portion for income is:

```
    public function dailyIncome()
    {

        return $this->makeModel()
            ->select(DB::raw("sum(cost) as income"),"date")
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->get();
    }
```

the query portion for income is:

```
 public function dailyExpense()
    {

        return $this->makeModel()
            ->select(DB::raw("sum(cost) as cost") , "date" , DB::raw("dayname(date) as calendar"))
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->get();
    }
```

Client portion:

```
 $scope.genereateReport = function () {

    $scope.choices = ['Daily', 'Monthly', 'Yearly'];
    $scope.$watch('selection', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        switch (newVal) {
            case 'Daily':

                $scope.url = $scope.base_path + 'dailyExpenses';
                $http.get($scope.url).success(function (response) {
                    $scope.expenses = response.data.expenses;
                    $scope.income = response.data.income;
                    $scope.totalExpenses = response.data.totalExpenses;


                });

                $scope.displayedCollection = [].concat($scope.expenses,$scope.income);
                console.log("collection:" + $scope.displayedCollection);
                $scope.totalExpenses = [].concat($scope.$totalExpenses);
                // $scope.income = [].concat($scope.income);
                //

                $scope.itemsByPage = 10;
                break;
 }
);
};
```

View Portion:

```
 <tr>
                                <th class="table-header-check">S.N</th>
                                <th st-sort="date" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1">Date</th>
                                <th st-sort="date" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1">Calandar</th>
                                <th st-sort="cost" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1">
                                    Expense
                                </th> <th st-sort="cost" class="table-header-repeat line-left minwidth-1">
                                    Income
                                </th>

                            </tr>


                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            <tr data-ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection track by $index" >
                                <td><% $index+1 %></td>
                                <td><%row.date%></td>
                                <td><%row.calendar%></td>
                                <td><%row.cost%></td>

                                <td><%income['row.date']%></td>


                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4">
                                   Total Expense: <%totalExpenses%>
                                </td>


                            </tr>
```

Result of above query in json form is:

[image]

View is like this without displaying income:
[image]

Desired output is like this..

[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjruV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your expected result by using sql `union` and `join`. Instead creating two separate functions, you can create one function and use raw query like below :

```
select e.date,e.cost,'0' as income
from test.expenses as e
where e.date not in (select i.date from test.incomes as i)
union all
select e.date, e.cost as cost, i.income as income
from test.expenses as e
inner join test.incomes as i on e.date = i.date 
union all
select i.date,'0' as cost,i.income as income
from test.incomes as i
where i.date not in (select e.date from test.expenses as e);
```

Here I created two tables named `expenses` and `incomes` with the given fields in the the table you specified above.And I use the query mentioned above and result is as follows.

[image]

I hope this is what you expected.

Comment: select expenses.date,expenses.cost,'0' as income
from expenses
where expenses.date not in (select incomes.date from incomes)
union all
select distinct(expenses.date), expenses.cost, incomes.cost
from expenses
inner join incomes on expenses.date = incomes.date 
union all
select incomes.date,'0' as cost,incomes.cost
from incomes
where incomes.date not in (select expenses.date from expenses)


esma distinct date haruko sum kasari nikalneho

Comment: select expenses.date,expenses.cost,'0' as income
from expenses
where expenses.date not in (select incomes.date from incomes)
union all
select distinct(expenses.date), sum(expenses.cost), sum(incomes.cost)
from expenses
inner join incomes on expenses.date = incomes.date 
union all
select incomes.date,'0' as cost,incomes.cost
from incomes
where incomes.date not in (select expenses.date from expenses)
esari sum garna khojda problem aauncha